# Double classes aren't working

Tags: html, css, class

I try to make a div with the properties of two classes. 
I want it to belong to the class `.form` and to `.small`

I tried the following:

The CSS:

```
.form  {
    width: 290px;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #767676;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    height: 25px;
}
.form  .small{
    height: 5px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<input name="name" class="form small" title="Username" maxlength="2048" />
```

Eventually the height of the input doesn't change to 5px, but stays at 25px
I really don't know what Im doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it's currently written, you are attempting to target an element with the class `.small` that is a descendent of an element with the class of `.form`. Bring those two together to target correctly:

```
.form.small {
  height: 5px;
}
```

Just for reference, as you had it written, it would be attempting to target something like this:

```
<div class='form'>
  <div class='small'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you use the class `small` within a class of `form` in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Your css is looking for an element that has class `small` that is a descendent of class `form`

Change it to `.form.small`

Answer (score 1):

For targeting future editing it is best as I think to do this:

CSS:

```
.from+small {
//Code of .from
//Code of .small
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="from+small"></div>
```

So what we do is created a CSS rule combining the `.from` and `.last` Rules it would help in future editing.